# Retrieve fund on safe address on a different network using safe-cli

Tags: gnosis-safe

Can you advise on a mistake made while sending fund on a safe address originally created on the Arbitrum network, but send to the same address on the Base network

while the safe could be recreated on the Base network with the same address (following the tutorial provided on [loom](https://www.loom.com/share/ca34aabcd62747fb9fb89bd463b4c741)) I'm still stuck somewhere

I first load load_cli_owners with the private key of the original owner.
That seems to work.

From there if I try to recover the stuck fund with drain or send_ether I got an error message with this part : Raises exception if it cannot be signed

If I check out the demo on the repo I do not type the : update command as the repo warning refrain me to test it on the base network that seems not to be known

what step am I missing ? How can i get to signed the transaction ?

Also the info return : Owners=None, but since the original signer is set as default sender after load_cli_owner this seems not where the issue lies

Thanks

Comment: just to confirm, are you using the cli because you are not able to access the multisig through the official ui?